# How to encrypt file using express multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

By having these simple few lines of code I've got file saved on server.

```
router.post('/upload',  upload.single('file'), function(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
    console.log(req.file);
    res.json({ success: true, message: 'Uploaded' });
});
```

I want to encrypt the file before it is get saved.

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: What problem to use crypto module? https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way for encrypting files is with Buffers using multer's `memoryStorage()`
and Node.js built-in [crypto library](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html).

```
import multer from 'multer'
import { scryptSync, createCipheriv } from 'crypto'
import { mkdirSync, existsSync, writeFileSync } from 'fs'

const upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() })

const encrypt = (buffer) => {
  // More info: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html
  const algorithm = 'aes-192-cbc'
  const iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 0)
  const key = scryptSync('super strong password', 'salt', 24)

  const cipher = createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv)
  return Buffer.concat([cipher.update(buffer), cipher.final()])
}

const saveEncryptedFile = (buffer, filePath) => {
  if (!existsSync(path.dirname(filePath))) {
    mkdirSync(path.dirname(filePath))
  }
  writeFileSync(filePath, encrypt(buffer))
}

router.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), ({ file }, res, next) => {
  saveEncryptedFile(file.buffer, './your-file-path')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

- Multer provides a rich set of events which can give you better
  control over your file uploads.

Therefore, the order of execution is:

1. onParseStart
2. onFileUploadStart/onFileUploadData...
3. onFileUploadComplete
4. onParseEnd

   - for encrypting we can use **[file-encryptor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-encryptor)** node module.

So,in your case your encrypting proccess should be in **onFileUploadComplete** by doing something like this:

```
    var fs = require('fs');       
    var encryptor = require('file-encryptor');
    var key = 'My Super Secret Key';          
    app.use(multer({      
            onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
                 console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path);
             // Encrypt file.
               encryptor.encryptFile(file, 'encryptedFile.dat', key, function(err) {
                  // Encryption complete.remove original file
                   fs.unlink(file);
                         });
                       }
                   }));
```

Comment: Outdated and not relevant anymore.