# Confused with encrypting files and file paths on multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'm pretty confused on how to encrypt both files themselves and the file paths using multer. I found this post in regards to encrypting files themselves: [How to encrypt file using express multer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449630/how-to-encrypt-file-using-express-multer), but my code wasn't working as it wasn't encrypting the files. I have this:

```
var fs = require('fs');       
var encryptor = require('file-encryptor');
var key = 'My Super Secret Key';     

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/'); // Make sure this folder exists
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        var ext = file.originalname.split('.').pop();
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }

}),
upload = multer({
  onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
             console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path);
         // Encrypt file.
           encryptor.encryptFile(file, 'encryptedFile.dat', key, function(err) {
              // Encryption complete.remove original file
               fs.unlink(file);
                     });
                   }, storage: storage }).single('uploadedFileField');
```

2nd Point: I wasn't able to find any resources to find out how to encrypt the file paths as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put `file.path` instead of `file` to `encryptor.encryptFile`.

I've looked up the source, and `encryptor.encryptFile` gets string as a first argument.

```
encryptor.encryptFile(file.path, 'encryptedFile.dat', key, callback);
```

Comment: None. However when I start the program (node index.js), "undefined" gets wrote to the console. Maybe a connection to this?